# Adding UIView subclass programmatically not drawing itself

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I don't understand how this works.  If I draw a UIView object to my UIViewController .xib file, then my UIView redraws itself.  If I add it to the subView like

`CustomView : UIView`

in UIViewController's viewDidLoad

```
CustomView *v = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:v];
```

The CustomView not draw itself.  I then tried to do

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

and I still get nothing.  Just a white background (different than the black background I was getting before), but none of my drawing.  How does it work when you add a UIView programmatically?  thanks.

Comment: Do you have any initialization logic in `initWithCoder:`?  This initializer is called instead of `initWithFrame:` when the view is loaded from a nib file.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy No I don't have any initialization there.  I remember reading something about it, and saw some posts regarding it.  Do I call initWithCoder?  Or do I still call initWithFrame?  Also, what would I initialize in initWithCoder since everything is done in my drawRect:?

Comment: You probably need to share your CustomView or at least the relevant parts.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, just needed to set the background color to white in my sharedInit method since that's what was getting set already in IB.  Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Also have you tried `[v setNeedsDisplay]` ?

Comment: try to loop through your views to see if your customView is present : for (UIView *v in self.view) { NSLog(@"class : %@", [v class]) }. If it is ok, your custom is probably under another view, so move it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply be setting the frame of `CustomView` incorrectly.

Each view has its own coordinate space, with (0, 0) at the upper left corner.  A view's `frame` is in its *parent's* coordinate space.  This mean that it is often wrong to set a view's `frame` to be the same as its superview's `frame`.

A view's `bounds` is in the view's own coordinate space.  So if you want to make your `CustomView` exactly cover its superview, you should set the `CustomView`'s `frame` to its superview's `bounds`.

Try this:

```
CustomView *v = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```